# "as very beautiful as" vs "as beautiful as"

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. She is as beautiful as her sister .
> 2. She is as very beautiful as her sister .

Can I use *'very'* between

> *'as'* + **'very'** + (adjective) + *'as'*

If not, why ?

Comment: No, You generally don't. But I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Sina, I don't think that's what the OP meant.

Comment: Look what I found: “If Mr. Trump's tax records are as very beautiful as he says, he should be eager to release them for public scrutiny. Will you release them by Super Tuesday? Don't Republican voters have a right to know?”  You can find it here https://www.cnsnews.com/news/article/melanie-hunter/trump-says-he-wont-release-tax-returns-yet. Seems it is possible, although rare

Comment: @Sina: that something can be found on the internet is not sufficient to regard it as an attestation.  And some of those are not examples of  the "**as** very X **as**" comparative pattern but simply "seen as very X".

Comment: @TRomano But some of them exist in English. Does not it mean the pattern is possible? And that some Englush speakers use it? Do not you belive in descriptive grammar? Or maybe you support prescriptive one?

Comment: @TRomsno I could link more sites, but I did not have enough time. So I linked my search results. No a good idea, though.

Comment: A pattern has to be in fairly widespread use before it achieves the status of being grammatical. One speaker in ten million doesn't cut it.

Comment: *She is very beautiful like her sister.* Or *She is as beautiful as her sister, which is very beautiful indeed.*

Comment: @Dear TRomano: Let me be more clear. I do not claim it is grammatical, nore I say it is common. I said it seems a possibal pattern being used in English, but of rare frequency. It needs more research before one can claim it is grammatical or it is not grammatical. the point is, structurally it is OK, but the main problem goes with the usage. Do you disagree?

Answer (score 3):

[very](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/very) adds emphasis to an adjective or adverb- it's heading toward a superlative.

This is appropriate when you are talking about one person or thing, for example

> John is very tall

It is not appropriate when comparing two people or things.

> John is taller than his brother ... ok
>
> John is **very** taller than his brother ... not ok

The [as.. as](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as) construction is also a comparison, and so the usage of very is not appropriate.

> John is as tall as his brother ... ok
>
> John is as **very** tall as his brother ... not ok

Comment: *John is very much taller than his brother.*

Comment: @nnnnn agreed, but then **very** is applied to **much** not to **taller**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this sentence is grammatical, but it is a bit strange. We only normally use this kind of grammar with emphatic adverbs like *extraordinarily*, not everyday adjectives like *very*. We would very rarely say something like this, although we might write it. Here are some examples from published books:

- Percy Bysshe Shelley produced work **as extraordinarily ambitious as** Prometheus Unbound, as clear and wideranging as A Defence of Poetry Defence of Poetry, as enduringly topical as The Mask of Anarchy, as often recited, quoted and anthologized as 'Ode to the West Wind'.
- The satiric intention here is to highlight the way that many reporters can have a fixed agenda ... types of information films, to parodies and satires that ironically critique the apparent ... as a cultural practice, the inter-relationship between modes of documentary and comedy is **as extraordinarily complex as** it is rich and diverse.

As you can see, this type of construction is only really used in ornate literary styles.